# Element appearing on different parts of the page when using IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have an element that is hidden and when you hover over a link it appears.  The only problem is that when using IE it appears way to the right (outside of the page) than when it does when you use Firefox (where it renders where I'd like it.  How do I fix this?  I don't know what part of the CSS was causing the problem so I just copied all of it.  I tried to leave off extraneous information as the page is pretty large.  Hopefully there's enough here to find out why it's not working right in IE..Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Simple Tabs with CSS &amp; jQuery</title>
<style type="text/css">
.hidden{
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    border:1px black inset;
    height:auto;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:14px;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    border:2px black double;
    list-style-type:none;
    left:1100px;
    top:300px;
    margin:1em 1em 1em 1em;
    display:none;
}
body {
margin:1em;
padding:0;
height:100%;
background-color:#cbcbcb;
color:#000000;  
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-style: thin;
}

h1 {font-size: 3em; margin: 20px 0;}
#centerColumn {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 1000px;
    height:1200px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999999;}


#header {
    border-style: thin;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -1em -1em 0 -1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 15.5em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('karrnsmall.jpeg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: scroll;

}

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}
ul.tabs li {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #eee;
    font-size:1.25em;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
table {
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px black solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th {
        border: 1px outset silver;
        background-color: silver;
        color: white;
      }
      tr {
        background-color: white;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      tr.striped {
        background-color:silver ;
      }
      td {
        padding: 1px 8px;
      }

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: right; 
    width: 99%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;

</style>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").hover(function(){
    $(".hidden").fadeIn(200);
},
function(){
    $(".hidden").fadeOut(200);
});
});
</script>

<body>
<div  class="hidden"><p>info here
   </p></div>
<div id="button"><a href="javascript:;">hover here</a></div></body>
```

Comment: You're missing an opening script tag

Comment: where is the openning <script> tag?

Comment: i was copying and pasting trying to not paste the whole page.  the script tag is there and it still doesn't work.  it works in both IE and Firefox, but in IE the box appears about 400 pixels to the right of Firefox.

Comment: I suspect you just need to clear the floats you have here, but what you pasted doesn;t seem to work for me at all on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dSYF7/

Answer (score 1):

1. Close your script tag
2. Add jquery library using this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` above the jquery code
3. Add the closing bracket in your css code for `.tab_content`
4. Check it and give us feedback

here a live example with corrected all the above http://jsbin.com/ukoba3

Comment: Got her fixed.  Thanks for the help, internetters.